# How to add attribute to parent div with ClassName in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm using ReactJS material UI [tabs navigation](https://mui.com/components/tabs/). I want to add one attribute named `tabindex` in one `div` with `class=MuiTabs-flexContainer MuiTabs-centered` having value -1 to its child nodes. I had tried but `tabindex=-1` is getting added to somewhere else:

Here in this screenshot, I need `tabindex=-1` in its child nodes i.e., `button` elements:

[image]

Here is the UI tabs part:

```
<Tabs value={value} id="tabSec">
  <Tab
    label={
      <span className={value === 0 ? "active-tab" : "custom-style-on-tab"}>
        ABC
      </span>
    }
  />

  <Tab
    label={
      <span className={value === 1 ? "active-tab" : "custom-style-on-tab"}>
        XYZ
      </span>
    }
  />
</Tabs>;
```

The function which I have done so far is:

```
const tabRoving = (element) => {
    element.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        if (element.contains(document.activeElement)) {
          element.childNodes.forEach(function (childElement) {
            if (childElement != document.activeElement) {
              childElement.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
              console.log("done");
            } else childElement.setAttribute("tabindex", "0");
          });
        }
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    tabRoving(document.getElementById("tabSec"));
  }, []);
```

How can I achieve this? Is this possible in ReactJS with material UI?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing a `tabIndex={-1}` prop on the `Tab` component? It should spread unused props down, eventually to the button.

> ### [Inheritance](https://mui.com/api/tab/#inheritance)
>
> While not explicitly documented above, the props of the ButtonBase
> component are also available on Tab. You can take advantage of this to
> target nested components.

> [Spread](https://mui.com/guides/api/#spread)
>
> Props supplied to a component which are not explicitly documented are
> spread to the root element; for instance, the `className` prop is
> applied to the root.

Pass a `tabIndex` prop to the `Tab` components:

```
<Tabs value={value} id="tabSec">
  <Tab
    tabIndex={-1}
    label={
      <span className={value === 0 ? "active-tab" : "custom-style-on-tab"}>
        ABC
      </span>
    }
  />

  <Tab
    tabIndex={-1}
    label={
      <span className={value === 1 ? "active-tab" : "custom-style-on-tab"}>
        XYZ
      </span>
    }
  />
</Tabs>
```